# Numpy: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log1p

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am encountering a warning during `np.log1p`: **`RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log1p`**, but I can't figure why. As far as I can tell, the input is proper. It contains only `float64` values between `-0.5` and `0.5` and some `NaNs`.

One issue is, as I try to bisect my array to find the offending conditions, it looks like any subpart of the array can be passed to `np.log1p` without any warnings.

As a result, I am sorry that I can't figure out how to generate a MWE from this, and it is too large to share, but perhaps someone can point out other debugging or investigation avenues that I could look into?

First, here is the warning:

```
z = np.log1p(x)
# /data/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log1p
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

Other calls that all trigger the same warning:

```
_ = np.log1p(x.values.copy(order='C'))
_ = np.log1p(np.ravel(x.values))
```

The input, however, seems proper:

```
x.info()
# <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
# DatetimeIndex: 4927 entries, 2000-01-03 to 2019-08-02
# Columns: 8119 entries, aaa to zzz
# dtypes: float64(8119)
# memory usage: 305.2 MB

x.values.flags
#   C_CONTIGUOUS : False
#   F_CONTIGUOUS : True
#   OWNDATA : False
#   WRITEABLE : True
#   ALIGNED : True
#   WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
#   UPDATEIFCOPY : False

(x.min().min(), x.max().max())
# (-0.5, 0.5)
```

The Numpy version is `1.15.4` (and Pandas is `0.23.4`).

Now, for the weird part: splitting the array (here 20 rows from the end) in two parts, none of the parts get a warning:

```
z0 = np.log1p(x.values[:-20])
z1 = np.log1p(x.values[-20:])
np.allclose(z, np.concatenate((z0, z1)), equal_nan=True)
# True
```

But, while the concatenated two parts are close to the result obtained in a single call (`z`), they are not identical:

```
np.allclose(z.values, np.concatenate((z0, z1)), equal_nan=True)
# True, but
np.allclose(z.values, np.concatenate((z0, z1)), equal_nan=True, atol=0, rtol=0)
# False
```

The difference is small, but I wonder how taking `log(1 + v)` on a single scalar can yield different results from time to time.

```
np.nanmax(np.abs(z.values - np.concatenate((z0, z1))))
# 1.1102230246251565e-16
```

What else should I try?

Comment: Have you tried updating to `numpy v1.16.4`?  Previous cases of the warning seem to be package related.  Perhaps share a link to the data on git

Comment: the problem has indeed disappeared with more recent versions of `numpy` (not sure exactly since when -- currently running `1.18.1`). @TrentonMcKinney: could you please convert your comment to an answer so I can upvote & accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Without data, it's difficult to offer a reason why this is happening.
- As per my original comment, the version of numpy used at the time the question was posted, was not the current version.

  - As such, **one possible solution is to update to the current version of the package.**
  - As per the comment from the OP, switching to the current version, 1.18.1, as of this posting, resolved the error.
- The function `np.log1p1` contains a default `where=True` parameter that seems to function slightly differently now, compared to the 1.15 version.

**1.15 where**: *Values of True indicate to calculate the ufunc at that position, values of False indicate to leave the value in the output alone.*

**1.18 where**: *This condition is broadcast over the input. At locations where the condition is True, the out array will be set to the ufunc result. Elsewhere, the out array will retain its original value. Note that if an uninitialized out array is created via the default `out=None`, locations within it where the condition is False will remain uninitialized.*

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the negative numbers:

```
z = np.log1p(x - x.min() + 1)
```